# Jenkins, Poll SCM update the hash manually

Tags: git, jenkins

I have the following configuration of Jenkins to publish automatically on TestFlight:

1- SCM Poll on bitbucket testflight branch
2- version bump (using fastlane)
3- git add & commit
4- git push testflight
5- build (using fastlane)
6- publish testflight (using fastlane)

The issue it's the following, after I perform the push Jenkins detect a new branch and start the building again giving birth to a deadly infinite building loop.
I would like to manually set the new Hash to the SCM Poll after the push.
... Any other approach the avoid this infinite loop it's welcome ^_^

Comment: As I know, SCM Poll could set a crontab-style interval like `H /3 * * *`, so it does not run all the time. Other triggers, like Gerrit Trigger I'm using, can filter branch and repo. It also provides variables like commit log message, revision, committer, author, and etc, which could be used to end the job in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding a check before starting the actual build.
I check the hash of the remote and the local branch, in case they are the same i skip the actual build, here is the bash script I run in jenkins

```
REMOTE=$(git ls-remote origin refs/heads/Feature/fastlane-jenkins | cut -f 1)
LOCAL=$(git rev-parse Feature/fastlane-jenkins)
if [ "$REMOTE" == "$LOCAL" ]; then
    echo "local branch already up to date, nothing need"
    exit
else
    echo "New commit found, performing release"
    git checkout Feature/fastlane-jenkins
    git pull origin Feature/fastlane-jenkins
    git push --set-upstream origin Feature/fastlane-jenkins
    /usr/local/bin/fastlane ios tf_all 
fi
```